# Why doesn't connect to the expected layer in Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to construct a variational autoencoder in Keras (2.2.4, with TensorFlow backend), here is my code:

```
dims = [1000, 256, 64, 32]
x_inputs = Input(shape=(dims[0],), name='inputs')
h = x_inputs

# internal layers in encoder
for i in range(n_stacks-1):
    h = Dense(dims[i + 1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='encoder_%d' % i)(h)

# hidden layer
z_mean = Dense(dims[-1], kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='z_mean')(h)
z_log_var = Dense(dims[-1], kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='z_log_var')(h)

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(dims[-1],), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

encoder = Model(inputs=x_inputs, outputs=z, name='encoder')
encoder_z_mean = Model(inputs=x_inputs, outputs=z_mean, name='encoder_z_mean')


# internal layers in decoder
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(dims[-1],), name='latent_inputs')
h = latent_inputs
for i in range(n_stacks-1, 0, -1):
    h = Dense(dims[i], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='decoder_%d' % i)(h)

# output
outputs = Dense(dims[0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform' name='mean')

decoder = Model(inputs=latent_inputs, outputs=outputs, name='decoder')

ae_output = decoder(encoder_z_mean(x_inputs))
ae = Model(inputs=x_inputs, outputs=ae_output, name='ae')
ae.summary()

vae_output = decoder(encoder(x_inputs))
vae = Model(inputs=x_inputs, outputs=vae_output, name='vae')
vae.summary()
```

The problem is I can print the summary of the "ae" and "vae" models, but when I train the ae model, it says

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'latent_inputs' with dtype float and shape [?,32]
```

In the model "decoder" is supposed to connect to the output of "encoder_z_mean" layer in the ae model. But when I print the summary of the "ae" model, "decoder" is actually connected to "encoder_z_mean[1][0]". Should it be "encoder_z_mean[0][0]"?

Answer (score 1):

A few corrections:

- `x_inputs` **is already** the input of the encoders, don't call it again with `encoder_z_mean(x_inputs)` or with `encoder(x_inputs)`

  - Besides creating a second node (the 1 that you are worried with, and that is not a problem), it may be the source of the error because it's not an extra input, but the same input
  - A healthy usage of this would need the creation of a new `Input(...)` tensor to be called
- The last `Dense` layer is not being called on a tensor. You probably want `(h)` there.

Do it this way:

```
# output - called h in the last layer
outputs = Dense(dims[0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform' name='mean')(h)

#unchanged
decoder = Model(inputs=latent_inputs, outputs=outputs, name='decoder')   

#adjusted inputs
ae_output = decoder(encoder_z_mean.output)
ae = Model(encoder_z_mean.input, ae_output, name='ae')
ae.summary()

vae_output = decoder(encoder.output)
vae = Model(encoder.input, vae_output, name='vae')
vae.summary()
```

It's possible that the `[1][0]` still occurs with the decoder, but this is not a problem at all. It means that the decoder itself has its own input node (number 0), and you created an extra input node (number 1) when you called it with the output of another model. This is harmless. The node 1 will be used while node 0 will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I corrected as you suggested. Now decoder is indeed connected to [0][0], but the same error still raise: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'latent_inputs' with dtype float and shape [?,32]. It seems weird.

Comment: @Tian, how are you trying to train? And what is your keras and your tensorflow versions?